# How to fix all "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-10

I'm try to learn and install laravel but that "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" thing comes when i already check the php version i use is compatible and composer installed
[image: PROBLEM]

So how to fix all of that problem things?

Comment: If you read the error message, you have a few specific issues: Several extensions are not enabled. Specifically, curl and file info. It's also detecting that you're using PHP 7.2, and Laravel 11 requires PHP 8.2.

Comment: Ignore the php version, mime-type-detection wants an older version. That might be fixed by enabling the extensions.

Comment: Tip: when posting console output, please use text and not an image of text. Images of text are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers, and search engine robots.

Comment: "mime-type-detection wants an older version" - whatever you mean by that, `league/mime-type-detection` is compatible with all PHP versions since 7.2, and it depends on `ext-fileinfo` since the very first release